# How to remove shortcut command Ctrl+E in Management Studio

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, ssms

I'm really frustrated by this shortcut because I commonly use both Emacs and Management Studio for different projects. However accidentally pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> in MS and expecting cursor to move to the end of the line, which it does in my Emacs configuration, can be really bad in MS if you are programming modifications to a database and, say, are not finished with your `WHERE` clauses.

I have found no way of redefining <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to something else, or remove the shortcut entirely. I know I can rightclick the EXECUTE button in the toolbar (no can do in Query menu) and remove the ampersand symbol there but it does not take, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> still executes my query.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

For now, there is workaround (map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to some other software):
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic855640-149-1.aspx

But apparently it cannot be disabled until next version (SQL 2011) :
http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/36303/disable-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

You could install [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/)(it's free). All of its features allow for keyboard shortcut binding, so all you need to do is open the options for one of its features and rebind the shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. I just tried it now for a coworker who has an identical problem as you. Works great!

Comment: FYI... FREE For SSMS versions prior to 2012. Licensing applies to 2012 and up.